# Why does str() not display names?

Tags: r

```
v <- c(a = 5, b = 6)
str(v)
#  Named num [1:2] 5 6
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "a" "b"
```

Now we set another attribute:

```
attr(v, "color") <- "blue"
str(v)
#  atomic [1:2] 5 6
#  - attr(*, "color")= chr "blue"
```

How come the names are no longer listed in the output of `str`?

And why `atomic`? I agree that `v` is atomic, but I would prefer `str` to be more precise and indicate that `v` is numeric.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good answer to "why" other than that's how `str.default` was written; it's a huge function that probably entailed a lot of design choices.

Comment: @joran: yes, you are quite on spot!  [it's me who  did 99% of it]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have improved R , i.e., the development version of R  aka "R-devel"  10 minutes ago, so it will behave +- as you expected, and no longer print  `atomic`  in such cases.

See my post in the relevant thread in the R-devel mailing list:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-November/075163.html

Answer (score 6):

You can read through `utils:::str.default` to see exactly why. Instead of two versions of `v`, let's compare two vectors:

```
v <- c(a = 5, b = 6)
u <- v; attr(u, "color") <- "blue"
```

Interestingly, `is.vector(u)` returns `FALSE`, and thus it gets handled a bit differently as `str` checks for `is.vector`. This doesn't seem to matter too much, because in both cases, naming is only handled specially if *it is the only attribute*. For example, lines 366-371 of `utils:::str.default`, which fall under `else if(is.atomic(object))`, (where the original `if` handled `if(is.vector(object) || ...)`, line 241)

```
if ((1 == length(a <- attributes(object))) && (names(a) == 
                "names")) 
                str1 <- paste(" Named vector", le.str)
            else {
                str1 <- paste(" atomic", le.str)
            }
```

Later, other attributes are printed only if they are not in `std.attr` (presumably "standard attributes"), which in the case of vectors includes names. Lines 499-507 (with my comments added):

```
if (give.attr) {
        nam <- names(a)    # a are the attributes, as seen above
        for (i in seq_along(a)) if (all(nam[i] != std.attr)) {

# in the case of our vector, std.attr is "names", set on line 101
# in other cases, it might include "row.names", "class", "dim"

            cat(indent.str, paste0("- attr(*, \"", nam[i], "\")="), 
                sep = "")
            strSub(a[[i]], give.length = give.length, indent.str = paste(indent.str, 
                ".."), nest.lev = nest.lev + 1)
        }
    }
```

This *might* be considered a bug. It seems like, at least for vectors, names are given special handling *if they are the only attribute*, but *if there are other attributes* the names attribute is ignored. 
If it is a bug, it's not clear to me what the benefits and risks are.

---

> I would prefer `str` to be more precise and indicate that `v` is numeric.

This seems like a design choice made by the `str` authors. I would prefer the default `stringsAsFactors` to be `FALSE`. I'm not sure whether you want a response to this part of your question, but of course there are other functions for learning about an object, `mode`, `is`, `typeof`, `dput`, `attributes`. Looking through the ~500 lines of `str.default` certainly makes me appreciate how flexible of a function it is and how many options are considered.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I used to rely blindly on `str`... Is there a way to explore the structure of an R object without missing any important part of it? `dput` would work for small objects, but sometimes I need to understand how a big object is structured (typically because I generated it with a poorly documented package).

Comment: No, I don't know a better way. As I think about it more, it seems more like a bug. I suppose the good news is that `str` has been around long enough that it's unlikely there are additional bugs?

Comment: OK. I think I'll wait a few days, and if nobody else answers I'll send a mail to R-devel to ask about it.